# windows keyboard menu-key missing, alternatives?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I am trying to use my HTPC with only a keyboard. Even though my keyboard is from Microsoft, they failed basic windows certification and did not include a menu-key, the one that shows a mouse cursor and a menu, usually located on the right of the space bar, between alt and control.

without that i can't do many actions.

On windows XP (or maybe NT? not sure) right alt+enter used to emulate that key and i would get the context menu... but on windows 7 that ain't so.

Is there any other key combination that can act as an alternative for context menu on selected items on windows 7?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The alternative for the menu key - also known as the Apps Key - that brings up the context menu is <kbd>Shift-F10</kbd>.

Some other possible solutions can be found here: 
[How can I open the context menu on start menu search results from the keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/94934/how-can-i-open-the-context-menu-on-start-menu-search-results-from-the-keyboard?rq=1)

E.g., if <kbd>Shift-F10</kbd> is impractical, you could create a one line AutoHotkey script to change it to something more convenient, like <kbd>Shift-F5</kbd>.

```
+F5::AppsKey
```

Comment: thanks! and damn twice that microsoft keyboard... f10 requires fn+f5...

Comment: @gcb I've added an AutoHotkey script to change the key to something else like Shift-F5.

Comment: Thanks @user-99572-is-fine! i tried using shift-f10 on that keyboard (shift-Fn-F4) but for some reason it does nothing... i will use autoHotkey... don't know why i wasn't using that before even for other things! excellent idea!